Connection to Oracle database in QGIS analogous to ArcGIS
I'm trying to connect to an Oracle database in QGIS. It works perfectly with ArcGIS Pro, where I insert the platform, instance, authentication type, username and password. However, in QGIS, there are so many more options I have to fill in before I can connect.
Can someone explain to me what I have to write in ‘Database’, ‘Host’, ‘Port’, ‘Options’, ‘Workspace’ and ‘Schema’ analogue to ArcGIS? I only have the instance (vat.xxxxx.de), the username and the password.
Is there a special plugin in QGIS that I can use to connect easily like in ArcGIS? Or is it just don't working in QGIS like in ArcGIS?
I am using 3.34.7
I have already connected a PostgreSQL database. With Oracle, I have entered the instance (of ArcGIS) in the Database field and the Host. I left the port at the default setting, but I had to change it for the PostgreSQL connection. Should I do the same here?
I have left the options, workspace and schema open until now.
The error code came up as an error message during the connection: ORA-12560.

I find that if you leave port or host blank the OK button is disabled even if the test connect reported ok.  I am using tnsnames.ora to provide the connection which has all that.  If I put the host and port as defined in the tnsnames.ora, the connection worked.  For the database I just repeated the name of the database.
My problem is how to do an OS authenticated connection where your windows user name is passed in...  In sqlplus I do: "sqlplus /database"  where database is defined in tnsnames.
The other problem is if a database has multiple host for transparent application failure for instance, would the connection be directly to one of the instance and thus negate the failover procedure.
